# If $\lim A_n$ exists, then $P(\lim A_n) = \lim P(A_n)$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Given a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of events with $\lim A_n = A$, I would like to show that $P(\lim A_n) = \lim P(A_n)$.

$\lim A_n = A$ implies that $\limsup A_n = A$. Thus $\bigcap \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=A$

Let $B_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ for every $n$. Then $B_n$ is non increasing.
We have:

$P(\lim A_n) = P(A) = P(\bigcap \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k)=P(\bigcap B_n) = \lim P(B_n)$ since $B_n$ non-increasing.
Thus $P(\lim A_n) = \lim P(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k))$.

How do I go from here to $\lim P(A_n)$?

Any hep would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What means $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n = A$?

Comment: $A_n \subseteq \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_n$, so $P(A_n) \leq P(\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_n)$. Combined with what you have already, this gives you $\limsup P(A_n) \leq P(\lim A_n)$. For the opposite inequality, presumably you also need to use that $\liminf A_n = A$. It would suffice to show that $P(\lim A_n) \leq \liminf P(A_n)$.

Comment: I think you want subscript $k$ (not $n$) in your $\bigcap\bigcup$ expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$ is an increasing sequence of events, $P(\limsup_n A_n) = \lim_n P(\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k)$.

Since $\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k$ is a decreasing sequence of events, $P(\liminf_n A_n) = \lim_n P(\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k)$.

Since $\lim_n A_n = \liminf_n A_n = \limsup_n A_n$, $P(\lim_n A_n) = P(\liminf_n A_n) = P(\limsup_n A_n)$.

But for all $n$, $P(\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k)\leq P(A_n)\leq P(\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k)$, so by squeezing, $P(A_n)$ converges to $P(\lim_n A_n)$.

Comment: Sounds like a wheel reinvention. Why not just use Fatou's Lemma? I posted an answer.

Comment: I further edited my answer to address comment of Gabriel Romon.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** The other answers seem to reinvent the wheel. Just use Fatou's Lemma

$$P(\liminf A_n) \le \liminf P(A_n) \le \limsup P(A_n) \le P(\limsup A_n)$$

- **Note to justify**: I really mean that I expect that at this point that the student knows the inequalities above collectively known Fatou's Lemma (and reverse Fatou's Lemma and the regular $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of real numbers in calculus). Maybe the student also knows integration version of Fatou's Lemma in measure theory, but I don't expect the student to know Fatou's Lemma in this sense (and thus of course in the expectation sense. Consequently further, I don't expect the student to use or even know $E[1_A]=P(A)$).
- **Edit: For further justification**, see below.

---

1. Actually, what we first have to prove is that $\lim P(A_n)$ exists, i.e. $\liminf P(A_n) = \limsup P(A_n)$ and then we define this common value as $\lim P(A_n)$. Then
2. Fatou's lemma says

$$P(\liminf A_n) \le \liminf P(A_n) \le \limsup P(A_n) \le P(\limsup A_n)$$

3. Now, saying '$\lim A_n$ exists' means '$\liminf A_n = \limsup A_n$' and then we define this common value as $\lim A_n$.
4. Then

$$P(\lim A_n) \le \liminf P(A_n) \le \limsup P(A_n) \le P(\lim A_n)$$

5. Hence, $\liminf P(A_n)  = \limsup P(A_n)$, i.e. $\lim P(A_n)$ exists
6. Finally, $P(\lim A_n) = \liminf P(A_n)  = \limsup P(A_n) =: \lim P(A_n)$

---

**Edit**: For the **Note** above and the comment of Gabriel Romon:

See for yourself that in David Williams' Probability with Martingales, you can prove Fatou's Lemma without any knowledge of measure-theoretic (Lebesgue) integration.

> [image]

Comment: I did not downvote. You're assuming the prior knowledge of the inequalities $P(\liminf A_n) \le \liminf P(A_n)$ and $\limsup P(A_n) \le P(\limsup A_n)$ (as statements or corollaries of Fatou's Lemma). However Fatou's Lemma is usually stated as $\int \liminf f_n d\mu \leq \liminf \int f_n d\mu$ for nonnegative measurable functions. A bit of work is required to show that $\liminf 1_{A_n}  = 1_{\liminf A_n}$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon I actually address this in the 'Note'. Here's the order of the Fatou's Lemma versions I learned: 1 - the measurable function thingy you said, 2 - the probability of events thingy I said, 3 - the (conditional) expectation version --> Here, we do not quite see how (2) follows from (1), but we do see how (2) follows from (3).

Comment: @GabrielRomon Nevertheless, we learn events before random variables. So we just take for granted that (1) and (2) are somehow related before we learn (3). However, you don't need to take (2) for granted. You can still prove (2) without using (1), (3), integration, expectations and measure theory and stuff. I don't believe this is unconventional. See David Williams' Probability with Martingales. The Fatou's Lemmas I state are in Chapter 2 (the '(2)'), but the Fatou's Lemmas you state are in Chapter 5 (the '(1)'). Later the probabilistic version is in Chapter 6 (the '(3)').

Comment: @GabrielRomon Anyhoo thanks!

Comment: @GabrielRomon so actually do you disagree with anything in my answer?

Comment: No, I even upvoted it.

Comment: @GabrielRomon right thanks XD

Answer (score 1):

A very useful way of thinking about this is to verify that $A=lim A_n$ exists iff $I_A=\lim I_{A_n}$ at every point. If you know DCT then  you get $P(A)=\lim P(A_n)$ immediately.

Comment: Sounds like a wheel reinvention or unnecessary use of the machinery of limits of random variables. Why not just use Fatou's Lemma? I posted an answer.

Comment: I further edited my answer to address comment of Gabriel Romon.